# facebook crawler is not crawling my prerenderd pages of angular application properly with prerender.io

Tags: angular, phantomjs, facebook-opengraph, prerender

i am using prerender.io as service to serve the static html pages of my angular application 
   when i am using facebook share functionality it is not showing my og:image

when i see how the page that has been scraped under scraped url in facebook debugger tool everything is fine the page appears to be the normal html page with og:title og:image and all the content of the pages

my question is why i am not able to see og:image on the sharing with facebook

is these problem related with prerender.io or something related to facebook crawler

i want to achieve this without serverside rendering because the the application is big and maded in the csr . it will take lot of effort make it

Comment: Hi there, could you send us an email with the URL you are testing so we can test it and see what the issue might be? Thank you! support@prerender.io

Comment: mail send @Prerender.io

Comment: @Prerender.io Any updates on this question? I have the same issue